# Reverse DNS for mail server

Tags: email, spam, reverse-dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does a Reverse DNS lookup work with regards to spam filters?](https://serverfault.com/questions/45272/how-does-a-reverse-dns-lookup-work-with-regards-to-spam-filters)

I have a question about setting a reverse DNS record for my mail server.

Which is the best way to configure:

1.)  The IP address reverses to the domain that is sending the email (ie. @mydomain.com)

2.)  The MX record target for all domains on the mail server (ie mail.mailserver.com)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PTR record should point to the mailserver hostname(that you should also have a A record for). Due to when email is sent in the headers you will see the server hostname and that is what the spamcheckers see.

A SPF record is used to verify the email for the  domain name is coming from the right server.

Comment: To put a little finer point on it: your A and PTR records should match the FQDN that the server identifies itself with in the SMTP HELO command.

Comment: It's worth noting that SPF records are less valuable than DK/DKIM. ISP's give a lot more weight to valid DK/DKIM signatures than SPF - at least in terms of a host's overall reputation. That said, you should employ both.

Answer (score 0):

You have an A record for the MTA, and an MX record to match. Add a PTR as well. Repeat for every MTA you want to use.